# Laravel - phpunit array assertion

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am trying to write a phpunit test so I can test that I'm getting the correct assertion, this test i currently have which is passing and works as intended.

```
/**
@test
*/
  $filmInfo = $this->postRequest();

        $this->assertFilm($this->requestData, $filmInfo['id']);

        $film = Film::findOrFail($filmInfo['id']);

        $this->assertEquals('LOTR', $filmInfo['name']);
        $this->assertEquals('Film about a ring', $filmInfo['description']);
        $this->assertEquals('Fantasy', $filmInfo['genre']['main']);
        $this->assertEquals('Adventure', $filmInfo['genre']['sub']);
    }
```

This is the request data array it is referring to:

```
    private function requestData(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'LOTR',
            'description' => 'Film about a ring',
            'main' => 'Fantasy',
            'sub' => 'Adventure',
        ];
    }
```

This test works fine and it passing but I want to test it within one assertion like so:

```
  $this->assertEquals([
            'name' => 'LOTR',
            'description' => 'Film about a ring',
            'genre' => [
                'main' => 'Fantasy',
                'sub' => 'Adventure'
            ]
            ,
        ], $filmInfo);
```

But I keep getting an error that the 2 arrays I'm asserting are not matching, do you guys have an idea on what could be causing this?

Comment: Does `$filmInfo` have more data in it? Can you dump/post it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like what the PHPUnit said, your array aren't matching. Your array should match with `all values` in `$filmInfo` array.

From your code, we can guessing that you aren't comparing the `id`. Maybe you can try this code:

```
$this->assertEquals(array_merge($filmInfo, [
    'name' => 'LOTR',
    'description' => 'Film about a ring',
    'genre' => [
        'main' => 'Fantasy',
        'sub' => 'Adventure'
    ],
]), $filmInfo);
```